# Anaconda's autocomplete function Sublime Text not working

Tags: python, sublimetext, python-3.10, sublimetext4, sublime-anaconda

I have installed the `Anaconda` plugin in Sublime Text Build 4126 and it doesn't work its autocomplete function. I don't know why. Anaconda's linting works indeed.

Python version: 3.10

Could you help please to detect and fix the problem?

Comment: What build number of Sublime are you using?

Comment: it's Build 4126

Comment: OK, so you're actually using Sublime Text 4. I updated your question with the new information. It's going to take me a little while to write an answer, as there are several steps you need to follow to fix it, but an answer is coming!

Comment: Many thanks! I look forward the answer!

Answer (score 0):

## Note:

**Since I wrote this answer, Anaconda has been updated to fix the problem. If you haven't already, simply update your Anaconda installation to v2.3.0 or newer.**

---

The `Anaconda` plugin comes with several other Python libraries bundled in, including [`jedi`](https://pypi.org/project/jedi/) (for autocompletion), [`autopep8`](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/) for code formatting, and several others. These libs are part of the `Anaconda` plugin itself, and are not installed as [Package Control dependencies](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/dependencies), so their versions don't change unless the plugin's author, [DamnWidget](https://github.com/DamnWidget), updates them manually. However, as they explained in a recent [comment](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/pull/915#issuecomment-1035406254), they haven't used Python or Sublime Text for a while, and are maintaining the plugin simply because it's popular with the community and no one else has stepped up to maintain it.

One of the included libraries is [`parso`](https://pypi.org/project/parso/), which parses Python source using a grammar file specific for the version of Python being used. This plugin happens to be where the bugs that are causing your problem lie. The first issue is that the included version of `parso`, which was last updated in May 2020, does not have grammar files for Python 3.10 (or beyond). (The grammar file for 3.9 is also exactly the same as the one for 3.8, but we'll fix that as well.) The second issue is that even if there were a 3.10 grammar file included, the `parso` source (and hence `Anaconda`), wouldn't be able to read it, so you don't get autocomplete.

We'll need to follow several steps to fix both these issues.

1. Open your Sublime Text `Packages` folder by clicking on **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**. Depending on your OS and whether or not you installed ST4 fresh or upgraded from ST3, this folder will be in different locations:

   - Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages` or `~/.config/sublime-text/Packages`
   - macOS/OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` or `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages`
   - Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages` or `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages`
   - Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages` or `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text\Data\Packages`
2. Open your Command Prompt, Powershell, or Terminal and navigate to a temporary directory, such as `C:\Temp` on Windows or `/tmp` on macOS or Linux.
3. Type in:

   ```
    git clone https://github.com/davidhalter/parso.git
   ```

   Alternatively, if you use a separate source control GUI program, use it to clone that repository someplace like one of the temp directories I mentioned.
4. Enter the just-created `parso` directory, then go into the `parso/python` directory. You'll see that among the files there are the `grammarXX[X].txt` files, where `XX[X]` starts at `36` and goes up to `312`. Open this folder in your operating system's file explorer app to make copying and pasting easier. Select all of the grammar files and copy them.
5. Back in the `Packages` window we opened earlier, navigate to `Anaconda/anaconda_lib/parso/python`. Paste the copied grammar files here. You'll be overwriting some of them, but that's okay - we *want* to do that. This will fix the first problem you're having.
6. Navigate up one level, so that your file explorer location is now `Packages/Anaconda/anaconda_lib/parso`. Open the file called `utils.py` in Sublime and navigate down to line 123. It should look like this:

   ```py
       match = re.match(r'(\d+)(?:\.(\d)(?:\.\d+)?)?$', version)
   ```

   We're going to add exactly one character. Replace the original line with this (make sure it's indented 4 spaces):

   ```py
       match = re.match(r'(\d+)(?:\.(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?)?$', version)
   #                                   ^ added this
   ```

   Save the file, and you're done! Restart Sublime Text, and Anaconda autocomplete should now work with versions 3.10 and above!

Please keep in mind that your changes will be overwritten the next time Anaconda is upgraded, but hopefully the next time that happens the new version will fix these bugs.

Comment: Thank very much for the answer! I will install Anaconda  v2.3.0 and see if it works!

Comment: I have installed the last version of Anaconda and unfortunately still not working the autocomplete function :(

Comment: I have upgrded Anaconda again and finally it's working :)